# how to connect d3.js and solr json response?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, solr

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
    <style>
        .axis {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!--/* adding d3.js lib*/-->
    
     
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dsv.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-fetch.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script>


        var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40 },
            width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


        var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

        var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);


        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickFormat(d3.num);




        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left")
            .ticks(10);



        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        
        
        
        
/* my data on json server
                
           d3.json("https://api.myjson.com/bins/xya14", function (error, data) 
             {

                        alert(data);
                        data.forEach(function (d) {
                        d.num = d.num;
                        d.value = +d.value;
                        alert(d.value);
                    });
 

            x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.num; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })]);
               
    */           
              
               
            
/* data on solr server*/               

                
        d3.json("http://192.168.2.4:8983/solr/vkash_collection/select?q=*:*&omitHeader=true", function (error, data) 
             {

                        alert(data);
                        data.forEach(function (d) {
                        d.num = d.num;
                        d.value = +d.value;
                        alert(d.value);
                    });     
               
            x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.num; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })]);

               
                        
               
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis)
                .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                .attr("dy", "-.55em")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Value ($)");

            svg.selectAll("bar")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("rect")
                .style("fill", "steelblue")
                .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.num); })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
                .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.value); });

        });

    </script>

</body>
```

I load one json file in solr which is have only two fields num and value.i take this url and use d3.json("solr url",function (data))..but I get nothing on the browser. how to connect d3.js ??

my js code snippet is here:

[image]

my solr url response is here:

[image]

Comment: do a search on async loading of data in d3

Comment: why do you attach it as images when it is just plain text?

Comment: Please add all code and examples as inline text, and make sure to add any debugging you've done to help limit the issue properly.

Comment: i added my code ..plz review .. solr json response  in image

Comment: Are you sure you're even allowed to make a request directly to Solr? Browser's can't access resources on different hosts by default, unless there's a proper header set. Your browser's development tools will show you how the request is made (Go to the network pane and see the request result, and check the console log as well).

Comment: sir ..for checking i load some json data on same server...my code fetch that data and able show barchart on brow..but when i put solr url i get fail,....if i hit solr url only in browser it showa solr response..

Comment: there is a big difference in loading a URL from the browser URL or by XMLHttpRequest/Fetch, these happen from within a (different) loaded URL

Comment: then what is efficient way to connect d3.js and solr...??

Comment: i just want to connect to solr